# URLSession - fails after app has been in the background (Swift 4.2)

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am using URLSession (Swift 4.2) to create a list of files in a remote directory. It works perfectly every time, except when the app has not been used for a long period of time (eg, 30+ minutes), or it has been in the background and then comes to the foreground. Clicking the button that calls the code for a second time always works... odd! Here is the code, am I doing something wrong? Do I need to "wake up" something if the app has been in the background?

```
    //START URL SESSION
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: gcDIR)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        //ERROR MEANS IMAGE NOT FOUND, ADD TO THE CACHE
        if error != nil {
            print("error: no files found")
            //return
        } else {

            //GET THE DATA
            if let data = data, let results = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
            {
                let lines = results.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                for line in lines
                {
                    let fields = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
                    for field in fields {
                        if field.contains(".png") {
                            gMaster.append(field)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }).resume()
```

Comment: Use breakpoints and debug it.

Comment: thanks Rakesha, when running in xcode debug mode, the issue doesn't occur, only when on a device and the app has been used for over 30 minutes.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the background modes capability is turned on?

Comment: Set a breakpoint for the line where the `URLSession` call is. Reproduce the issue. Check if your `URLSession` is called. Otherwise check where the control is going because button action will definitely be called when a button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks again Rakesha - after a few hours of debugging I was able to replicate the issues (app needs to be asleep for over an hour) and with improved flow following URLSession returning an error, the issue is now fixed. Thanks for your help, my app users now have a much better experience, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @JamesKent, I'm facing a very similar issue. Any recollection how you got it fixed? 